# I have just one big partition with windows loader in it... how to install Ubuntu alongside windows in that case?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-vista

I want to install Ubuntu on an old Windows Vista laptop.

I need to maintain the Vista (yes, I know, it sucks), so I decided to create a partition alongside while installing it.

But I don't know what to do after I select "something else".

The next screen shows the partition list:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 ntfs size:1572 MB used:145 MB
/dev/sda2 ntfs size:198475 MB used: unknown Windows Vista (loader)
```

And that's all I've got there.

If I select /dev/sda and then click "New Partition Table..." I get this message that says "You have selected an entire device to partition. If you proceed with creating a new partition table on the device, then all current partitions will be removed".

I don't want to remove all partitions... but I just have the windows loader as the big partition that has almost the whole disk.

What should I do?

I've installed ubuntu before and other windows machine, but in the first case I did have some free allocated space... I don't know how to manage this, when I've read that you should not touch the windows loader partition...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to shrink the volume of sda2 to allow space to "install along side Windows". Then you will have the option to install as you wanted, or you can "do something else" and create your own swap, and "/" root partition and install that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the Partition, not the drive. /dev/sda is the drive, where /dev/sda1 is the first partition, and /dev/sda2 is your Windows partition.....so select /dev/sda1

Comment: Thanks, but that partition is so small (1 GB), and the big one is the one with the windows loader...

Comment: Then I think your only option is to install it along side Windows.

Comment: That´s exactly what I want, but I´m a bit scared to do so, because the only partition available is the windows loader... and I´ve read somewhere that I shouldn´t use that one.

Comment: you may just use `install alongside windows`

Comment: But I don´t have that option, that´s why I´ve chosen "other"

Comment: I mean "something else"